# Laravel Stripe Cashier - Working with cancellation, quantity and grace period

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Stripe API (PHP).

My website allows users to create free homepages. A user can create many homepages. My website charges users per each website.

When a user creates his first homepage, I create a subscription via Stripe API and charges them $5 per month.

When a user creates his second homepage, I increment quantity on the existing subscription so it becomes $10 per month.

When a user cancels his second homepage, I decrement quantity on the existing subscription so it becomes $5 per month in the next billing cycle - meaning that the second homepage is still active until the current billing cycle ends.

However, Stripe API does not seem to provide the grace period for the second homepage that was cancelled? Does it? How do I work that out? Are the above steps correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you decrease the `quantity` it is always instant today. You can't defer this to the end of the month at the moment. There are multiple ways to approach this though:

- Decrease the quantity in Stripe, disable proration with `proration_behavior: 'none'` and track in your own database that one extra quantity was paid for until the end of the period.
- Use Subscription Schedules to track phases on your Subscription. This allows you to control the change that will happen when the Subscription renews to bring the quantity back down by N at that point: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules